# Search first 3 and last 5 digit/characters from Col A against Col B

Tags: excel

I'd like to check the first 3 digit/characters and the last 5 digits/ characters from a cell on Column A against the cell on Column B, if found Column C will return True. Column A consist 10 digits/chars and column B has last 15 digit/char. Also column A has 200 rows/data whereas on Column B has 1000 data/rows.

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1,B1))
```

but return True if found the same data.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula searches for the whole number in A1 in B1. Use the following formula to search only the first 3 and last 5 characters:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(LEFT(A1,3),B1)+SEARCH(RIGHT(A1,5),B1))
```

To search the same in the whole column B, use the following array formula, entered with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH("*"&LEFT(A1,3)&"*",TEXT(B1:B2,0),0)+MATCH("*"&LEFT(A1,3)&"*",TEXT(B1:B2,0),0))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, it works!. Just a follow-up question, Column A is my reference to search the first 3 and last 5 char/digit on any cell in column -B. If say the first 3 and last 5 char/digit found or match on any cell in column-B then will return True.